# How can I solve a https connecition error when data scraping? might be a problem of the company VNP

Tags: web-scraping, request, vpn

I am trying to do a request but I get the following error:

```
SSLError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='transparency.entsoe.eu', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /api?documentType=A44&in_Domain=10YES-REE------0&out_Domain=10YES-REE------0&securityToken=278a7d7b-0955-4fda-af4c-7843c28305e6&periodStart=202011302300&periodEnd=202012312300 (Caused by SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: self signed certificate in certificate chain (_ssl.c:1125)')))
```

It might be related to my VPN company...

Could somebody help me with this issue?

Comment: It could be related to any point in the traffic, VPN traffic shouldn't serve any self-signed certs unless there is a proxy between you and `transparency.entsoe.eu` or if this host itself is served over a self-signed cert, If you don't care about SSL and you trust this host you could skip this check against the CA trust store - in python I think using `ssl_verify=false`  or you could trust the certificate they serve so that the check won't fail.

Comment: `self signed certificate in certificate chain` - what have you tried to resolve this? Also, is this in any way related to programming?